Criticism with modals
My teacher says that we don't use "can't have" and "couldn't have" to critize people. What do you think for example these two examples in my opinion show critisizm

You couldn't have done more things wrong.


You can't have done anything worse.


Just a note: It's couldn't (with an n). It stands for "could not" just like how "can't" stands for "can not".

Ok. But what do you think about my question?

done more things incorrectly or inaccurately. or more badly.  to do wrong means to do something immoral/not just. But I would not use it comparatively like that. You couldn't do more wrong than he does.

I just want to if it's  fine to use these two modals in this form can't have and couldn't have to critize people unlike must which is only used for giving orders

You can criticise people using almost any modal or other form of words. "You must do better" "You should know better" "You could have died" "You might think of other people sometimes" "You may be the stupidest person I've ever met" etc. You need to be clearer about the rule your teacher taught you.

I think I know all i need now thank youu

It's criticize and criticism.

I think, to get a really good answer, you need to edit the question to tell more about why you're teacher said they won't work. Maybe they were focusing on a certain context or usage.

@KateBunting or criticise in British English.

"You couldn't have done this worse if you tried" is correct and idiomatic, but rude. Is your teacher maybe trying explain the rudeness level of these criticisms? e.g. "You could have started on this a little earlier" is "gentle" criticism, "you should have started on this earlier" is tough but fair, and "you can't have expected to get a good grade starting this essay on the last day" is very harsh!

The other interpretation: if your teacher was talking specifically in the present perfect, "You shouldn't have done that" is a criticism, while "you couldn't have done that" is doubting that something actually happened.

Certainly could sounds right and can sounds wrong.
At a deeper level I think this is about tense.

You could not (in the past) have done (that action in the past) this worse

compared to

You can not (in the present) have done (that action in the past) this worse

Indeed, the latter doesn't really make sense because you can never have done anything differently in the present to how you did it in the past, unless you are a time traveller!
